# How to interpret the following input to the execute method of the STAPLE filter object: Execute(const Image & image1)?

Tags: simpleitk

I am trying to use the STAPLE filter, provided by Simple ITK. I do not understand how to interpret the input in the execute method, documentation is missing. For example:

Execute(const Image &image1) OR Execute(const Image &image1, const Image &image2)

From: https://simpleitk.org/doxygen/latest/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1STAPLEImageFilter.html

What does const Image mean?
What & operation will perform on Image and image1?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Const is a C++ keyword meaning that the input parameter will not be modified in the method.  The ampersand, '&', means the parameter is being passed to the method by reference.  That means the entire input image isn't put on the stack, just a reference (address) to it.

These are performance/implementation issues that you don't really need to worry about.  Basically you are passing one or more images to the STAPLE filter for analysis.

Comment: Thanks for demystifying!